# vb. net search about sentence and return the first word index

Tags: vb.net, linq, arabic

i was asked a question here but i forget to explain my problem well.. so my problem is that I have a huge string in arabic which i want to search about a sentences in it and if i found it return the first word index (word index not character) ..

for example:

```
Dim myString as String = "Fundamentally programs manipulate numbers and text. These are the building blocks of all programs. Programming languages let you use them in different ways, eg adding numbers, etc, or storing data on disk for later retrieval.. Fundamentally programs manipulate numbers and text."
```

so.. when i search about (programs manipulate) i want to return: 1 and 36 .. any suggestions by the best way ? if with linq i will appreciated .. thanx

Comment: will the words always be delimited by a `space`???

Comment: Secondly this hardly seems constructive. You have not posted anything that you have tried so far. Other than being arabic language it is purely a vb.net related question as it is a "how to code" this question not "is this grammatically correct in arabic" therefore really shouldnt have the tag `arabic`... Lastly a simple search of google will help you on this homework assignment. You know that you are looking for the index's of the first item in the `Dim locater as string = mystring.split(" ")(0)' the rest is on you..

Comment: Have a look on this one.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx

Comment: This is a non-trivial task. You'd need to parse out your string into words grouped by sentences. But defining "word" and "sentence" is very, very tricky. For example, how many words and sentences are there in the following: `Mr. Smith-Johnson said "Capital Idea!" to Josè Jr. Meanwhile, 37 sky troopers - or was it 3700? - fired off 50-200 rockets each.`

Comment: OK my friend Skindeep2366 why you are very upset .. if I very newbie in programming why u upset .. i searched a google more than once with no luck .. so i came here in a pro place to ask my question .. secondly i give an example in english because i know that the most here talking in english not in arabic .. did i understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something similar to this.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var str = "Fundamentally programs manipulate numbers and text. These are the building blocks of all programs. Programming languages let you use them in different ways, eg adding numbers, etc, or storing data on disk for later retrieval.. Fundamentally programs manipulate numbers and text.";
        foreach (var index in GetIndexes(str, "programs manipulate",' '))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(index);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    public static IEnumerable<int> GetIndexes(string str, string search,params char[] delimiters)
    {
        var index = 0;

        var words = str.Split(delimiters).ToList();
        var searchwords = search.Split(delimiters);

        while (words.Any())
        {
            if (words.Take(searchwords.Length).SequenceEqual(searchwords))
                yield return index;

            words.RemoveAt(0);
            index += 1;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: thank you very much my friend Mathew .. work like a charm